# CPLEX 12.8, Visual Studio 2015 Error: Cannot open include file

Tags: visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, cplex

I'm novice to these but here it goes:

I've installed IBM ILOG CPLEX 12.8 (on Windows 10, 64-bit) and wanted to build my own project on Visual Studio 2015.

Using the example "blend.cpp" provided in the CPLEX directory (C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio128\cplex\examples\src\cpp), I've followed the instructions given at the readme (C:/Program%20Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/c_cpp.html) for the "Building your own project which links with CPLEX". However, still I've received the error: **C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ilcplex/ilocplex.h': No such file or directory.**

What should I do to prevent this error?

Thanks.

Comment: There are 685 posts that mention C1083, have you read those? Maybe they explain what to do?

Comment: This question was cross-posted [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=9cb54d71-2123-4c80-a8c8-ff03d04b7ece&ps=25).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyhow, instead of copying the directory paths either with " " or with nothing added:

I simply browsed to the directories via the interface and it worked.

Weird.

Comment: mezbaha: you should [accept your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so that others know this issue is resolved.

Comment: oh sorry, i do not know how things go around here. thanks for the reminder rkersh